# Need foreach to skip/ignore missing array

Tags: php

I have this php code for inserting data from my from;

```
$i = 1;
foreach ( $_POST['form'] as $val => $form ){   
    $Style = $_POST['form'][$i]['style'];
    $Dim= $_POST['form'][$i]['Dim'];
    $Colour= $_POST['form'][$i]['Colour'];
    $Quantity= $_POST['form'][$i]['Quantity'];

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO orders(Cus_ID, Style, Dimensions, Colour, Quantity) VALUES(:Cus_ID,:Style,:Dimensions,:Colour,:Quantity)");

    $stmt->execute(array(':Cus_ID' => $Cus_ID, ':Style' => $Style, ':Dimensions' => $Dim, ':Colour' => $Colour, ':Quantity' => $Quantity));  

    $i++;
}
```

When I submit my form  a var_dump give me something like this;

```
array (size=3)
  'form' => 
    array (size=3)
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'style' => string '0' (length=1)
          'Dim' => string '0' (length=1)
          'Colour' => string '0' (length=1)
          'Quantity' => string '' (length=0)
      2 => 
        array (size=4)
          'style' => string '0' (length=1)
          'Dim' => string '0' (length=1)
          'Colour' => string '0' (length=1)
          'Quantity' => string '' (length=0)
      3 => 
        array (size=4)
          'style' => string '0' (length=1)
          'Dim' => string '0' (length=1)
          'Colour' => string '0' (length=1)
          'Quantity' => string '' (length=0)
  'submit' => string 'Place Order' (length=11)
```

Everything is fine and dandy, but when i delete part of my form the submitted aray will end up something like this;

```
array (size=2)
  'form' => 
    array (size=2)
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'style' => string '0' (length=1)
          'Dim' => string '0' (length=1)
          'Colour' => string '0' (length=1)
          'Quantity' => string '' (length=0)
      3 => 
        array (size=4)
          'style' => string '0' (length=1)
          'Dim' => string '0' (length=1)
          'Colour' => string '0' (length=1)
          'Quantity' => string '' (length=0)
  'submit' => string 'Place Order' (length=11)
```

To which the php trys to enter the '2nd' array which doesn't exist, is it possible to have the php 'skip/ignore' any arrays that are missing (the array are unlimited and any random number could be missing)

Comment: Yes it is, but why are you even using `$i`? You're doing `foreach($_POST['form'] as $key => $form)`, so just access `$form` directly.

Comment: Add `if (!isset($_POST['form'][$i])) continue;` at the very start inside your loop. This is what you want but it's not what you should be doing. Read up on [`foreach loop`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, simply [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) if the current index isn't set.

However, there is no reason for you to be using `$i` at all. Your `foreach` loop is written to give you access to each form as `$form`, so *just use `$form`*:

```
foreach ( $_POST['form'] as $val => $form ){  
    # No! 
    $Style = $_POST['form'][$i]['style'];
    $Dim   = $_POST['form'][$i]['Dim'];

    # Yes!
    $Style = $form['style'];
    $Dim   = $form['Dim'];

    #...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In foreach, you don't need to use `$i`. `$val` is the key of the subarray. `$form` IS the subarray and can be used as:

```
foreach ( $_POST['form'] as $val => $form ){   
    $Style = $form['style'];
    $Dim= $form['Dim'];
    $Colour= $form['Colour'];
    $Quantity= $form['Quantity'];

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO orders(Cus_ID, Style, Dimensions, Colour, Quantity) VALUES(:Cus_ID,:Style,:Dimensions,:Colour,:Quantity)");

    $stmt->execute(array(':Cus_ID' => $Cus_ID, ':Style' => $Style, ':Dimensions' => $Dim, ':Colour' => $Colour, ':Quantity' => $Quantity));  

}
```

So, to answer your question, foreach never reaches missing array. It loops through array elements and so, if the array has two elements, it will iterate two times. If the array has three elements, it will iterate 3 times and so on.